# Executing a selected test when a particular data row is selected

Tags: telerik, data-driven-tests, telerik-test-studio, testautomationfx

I'm trying to do a simple if else function during a particular number of data row executed for Data Driven Testing.

The idea is simply to execute test "x" if the current data row is "x". I found a property (CurrentDataRow) in Telerik documents to do exactly this but i can't seem to manipulate the property to achieve this.Here's the idea of the code :

```
public void Login_CodedStep()
   {                        
      if (ExecutionContext.CurrentDataRow. ***** == 1 {
        this.ExecuteTest("Login\\VerifyFailLogin.tstest");                       
         }                
     }
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Best Regards, 
Pravin

Comment: Is this the droid you are looking for `this.ExecutionContext.DataSource.Rows.IndexOf(this.ExecutionContext.CurrentDataRow);`

Comment: `Item[Int32]` or `.Item[String]` as a datarow should be the Datarow from .Net

Comment: Hi Pierre, how do we incorporate this into the if else statement to ensure if the first datatable row is executed, VerifyFailLogin.tstest is executed?